# ActiveRecord query based on belongs_to association count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a User model that has may scores

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scores
```

I want to be able to query my postgresql db to return users that have at least one score.

```
User.where(scores.count >= 1)
```

Any idea on how to accomplish this without adding a counter_cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more Rails-ish way would be

```
User.joins(:scores).where('scores.user_id > 0')
```

Also, I think SELECT count(*) will return the number of users, not the user rows themselves, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: How would you then add an additional condition such as gender: "female" ?

Comment: You can extend the #where condition if you know all the conditions ahead of time - you'd have to refer to each table and column if the columns were in both tables, like users.id, probably not a concern unless you have gendered scores - or chain several #where clauses together, `User.joins(:scores).where('scores.user_id > 0').where('gender = ?', 'female')`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM scores WHERE scores.user_id = users.id)
```